# My \cite command doesn't work: how to fix that?

Tags: apacite

My \cite{} command doesn't seem to work as expected while my bibliographical references are correctly set. How could I fix that? Could you please tell me if I didn't forget something anywhere? This is my MWE:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage[left=4.5cm,right=4.5cm,top=5cm,bottom=5cm]{geometry}
    \onehalfspacing
    \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
    \usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
    \usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
    \makeindex[name=npr, title=Index des noms cités] 
    \makeindex[name=mat, title=Index des matières]
    \begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{Tufte2002,
 author = {Tufte, Blabla},
 year = {2002},
 title = {A title},
 
}
\end{filecontents}
    
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
    \title{A title}
    
    \maketitle
    
    
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{A title}
    
    \cite{Tufte2002}
    
    \bibnewpage 
    {%start grouping
      \doublespacing % <====================================================
      \raggedright 
      \nocite{}
      \bibliographystyle{apacite} 
        \bibliography{mybib}
    }%end grouping
    
    \phantomsection
    \cleardoublepage
    \printindex[npr] 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index des noms cités}
    \printindex[mat]
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index des matières}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Load `apacite` after `hyperref`.

Comment: It probably doesn't have anything to do with your immediate problem, but `\nocite{}` looks wrong. If you want to add all entries from the `.bib` file to the bibliography, you want to use `\nocite{*}`. I would remove the `\nocite{}`, but I should stress again that this probably won't resolve the problem at hand.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could describe in more detail how the `\cite` commands don't work for you after you applied the changes suggested in the answer below. Do you get error messages (if so, what do the messages say)? Does the output look wrong (if so, what output do you get, what do you expect instead)? ...

Answer (score 3):

Further reducing the MWE results in the following example code that upon compiling twice results in the following error message:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{Tufte2002,
 author = {Tufte, Blabla},
 year = {2002},
 title = {A title},
 
}
\end{filecontents}
    
\begin{document}
    
\cite{Tufte2002}

\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{mybib} 

\end{document}
```

---

```
Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a 
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
l.17 \cite{Tufte2002}
```

This can be solved by inverting the load order of `apacite` and `hyperref`, loading `apacite` *after* `hyperref`.

This is also mentioned in the `apacite` manual:

> The `hyperref` package turns (cross-) references into hypertext links.
> This can beused in conjunction with a program such as `LATEX2HTML` to
> compose `.html` files with clickable links, to internet pages or within the
> same document, or it can be used to create a `.pdf` document with clickable
> crossreferences.  Evidently, citations are also references.  Therefore,
> the `hyperref` package transforms these into hypertext links as well, and
> needs to redefine the citation commands and reference list commands in
> order to do so.  These redefinitions have caused severe
> incompatibility problems between `apacite` and `hyperref` in the past.  These
> incompatibility problems have been solved and **apacite is compatible
> with `hyperref`, provided that `apacite` is loaded *after* `hyperref`.**

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Waht does "it does not work" mean specifically? According to my tests, my suggestion works both with my example code, as well as with the original example from your question. Do you still get the same error messages?

Comment: After compiling, even several times, the year of the book quoted doesn't appear in the text body.

Comment: Which example code did you use? The exact one from my answer? Did you also make sure, to load `apacite` after `hyperref` (not the case in the example code in my question since I originally wanted to show a more minimal example that still produces the issue)? Do you get any error messages? Of so, which?

Comment: No, no, excuse-me: it works. I just didn't load Apacite after Hyperref. But when I compile my whole document, it doesn't work anymore.